# Evaluated expression not being parsed after updating to angular 1.2.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the syntax i had with 1.0.8

```
<div ng-click="go('/albumDetail/{{album.albumID}}')">
```

And it worked perfectly. However, after updating to 1.2.5 (which also involved using the newly seperated routing module, not sure if thats related or not), album.albumID is not being parsed and is being sent as is. What is hapenning here ?

Comment: See the 1.0 to 1.2 migration guide (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration), specifically the section, "Interpolations inside DOM event handlers are now disallowed".

Comment: Thanks. But i dont get it. How am i now supposed to pass a variable value to a function now ? How would you re-write the code above ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are doing interpolation to begin with. Is there any reason why you cannot try: `go('/albumDetail/' + album.albumID)`?

Comment: Goodness me, i feel like such a bonehead. I never knew you could do that :/ If you can post this as an answer, i would be happy to accept and vote it up. Thanks a lot man :)

Comment: Not a problem! Assuming you are using `$scope`, don't forget all the variables you define under it are available by their names in your HTML. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.2 versions of Angular disallow interpolations inside DOM event handlers.

(cf. docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration)

Instead of using interpolation, you could just use plain JavaScript for the event handler expression to form your parameter:

```
go('/albumDetail/' + album.albumID)
```